# Angular: ng-options, replacing both array and model value on update

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm working on a model which for every property update, sends itself to the server and gets recalculated. As most properties are based on lists I'm using `<select>`/ "*dropdown*" extensively.

An example on how the logic is set up:

```
{
  NumberList: ['123', '456', '789']
  Number: 0
}
```

User picks "**123**" from `NumberList`, Server responds with

```
{
  NumberList: ['123', '456', '789']
  Number: 123,
  OtherNumberList: ['999', '888', '777'],
  OtherNumber: 0
}
```

My problem is that once the user picks 123 it doesn't "stick" in the View. The select lists "flashes" (in lack of a better decription) and reverts back to 0 / Empty option. In the model however the property is correctly reflected.

Based on a old similar question here on SO I tried with ng-repeat. This almost works, but weirdly fails **on some properties**.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="model.Number" ng-change="mCtrl.updateModel(index)">
    <option ng-repeat="Number in model.NumberList" value="{{Number}}" ng-selected="model.Number == Number">{{Number}}</option>
</select>
```

My current template however fails **on all properties**. Thinking that it's easier to solve a general problem I've stuck with it.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="val for val in NumberList" ng-model="model.Number"></select>
```

*For the hell of it I've tried using `track by`, but with no luck.*

I'm really stumped on what the problem is. The only idea I have left is that since the list are arrays of strings, while the number being a number there is a type inequality. However I'm assuming ngOptions doesn't do type checking ..?

**Update**: As requested, the update logic.
The `update` function gets called from the server once the model is updated. The call to the server is done from ngChange via a Service.

```
'update': function (index, model) {
    $window.logger('Server called update ::');
    // The array below is a list of all models
    MyService.listOfModels[index] = model;
    // Yes, this is a bit quick'n'dirty ...
    $rootScope.$apply();
}
```

Comment: most likely your problem is because you are reassigning the object instead of extending it, meaning you are destroying the model and recreating it, which probably causes np-options to reset it self. can you post your update logic? or maybe create a fiddler??

Comment: You're correct: The entire object is re-created on the server side and gets replaced in the array with its updated self. I'll add a snippet of the update logic.

Comment: ca you try to extend the object instead of recreating it?

Comment: That is my worst-case scenario as the models are incredibly complex. So if I am to do it I must be sure that I've tried every other possibility.

Comment: why don't you take the elements select options out of the model and update just those as needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right to question but wrong in your assumption:

> The only idea I have left is that since the list are arrays of
>   strings, while the number being a number there is a type inequality.
>   However I'm assuming ngOptions doesn't do type checking ..?

... because the ngOptions directive [does](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/083f496d46415c01fec6dfa012da63235d0996e4/src/ng/directive/select.js) use `===` for setting the selected value. These types need to match if you wish for the selection to be maintained after the server responds.

#### Another note

As pointed out in your question's comments and in another answer, you may also run into issues sourced from your reassigning of a new object to the model, whereas one way or another, you should probably be extending the existing object.

You may be able to use `angular.extend` without much change to your code:

```
'update': function (index, model) {
...
     angular.extend(MyService.listOfModels[index], model );
...
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/K3MHnAWOSKPzjB7aRL43?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you update your model object and replace it with new one, so bindings to property of the old one stay in tack.
See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/uxu3L/

First controller doing what you are doing

Second one updates model, rather than replacing it

```
var app = window.app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('Ctrl',['$scope','$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    this.model = {       
      NumberList: ['123', '456', '789'],
      Number: 123
    }

    this.postBack = function() {        
        $timeout(function() {
            this.model = {
              NumberList: ['123', '456', '789'],
              Number: 123,
              OtherNumberList: ['999', '888', '777'],
              OtherNumber: 0
            }               
        }.bind(this))       
    }.bind(this)   
}])

app.controller('Ctrl2',['$scope','$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    this.model = {      
      NumberList: ['123', '456', '789'],
      Number: 123
    }

    this.postBack = function() {        
        $timeout(function() {
            this.model.OtherNumberList=['999', '888', '777']
            this.model.OtherNumber= 0         
        }.bind(this))        
    }.bind(this)    
}])
```

Comment: I see that destroying and replacing the object also creates new bindings. However I don't understand why the default value isn't correctly set but rather reverts back to 0.

Comment: So what properties it works for and what doesnt? works for selects where source list is list of objects?

Comment: All lists are strings of numbers. However there might be something with the formatting that separates them (decimal vs non-decimal). I'll have to check it out. Thanks a lot!